# postgres database replication on windows 8

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I am using postgres 9.4 on two different windows machines. Both machines are having Windows-8 operating system.

I want to create replicate environment i.e. to make one master and other slave db.

I have followed all the steps mentioned on the link below :
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial

After copying the file from data folder of master machine to slave machine (excluding pg_xlog folder and postgresql.conf file), when I tried to start my slave db, it prompt me the error as below -

[image]

> "The postgresql-9.4 service on Local Computer started and then
>   stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use....."

Even I am not able to open the log file which is there in pg_log folder on the slave (Access is denied), as I copied it from slave.

Can anyone help me out of this issue?